# How to set a Slot receiving every Widget action in Qt

Tags: qt

Suppose I've a Qt app based on QWidget, in which I'd like to obtain a "feedback" everytime I press a QPushButton, I rotate a QDial, I press a mouse button. My question is: how can I set a slot that informs me everytime something happened inside my app built for a touchscreen, in which I need to know when user does something on it.
MousePressEvent partially solves my problem; so when user touches the screen, MousePressEvent warns me about it. Problem is related to widgets as QPushButtons or QDials.
At the moment, I've already arranged my widgets with a lot of subwidgets; number of pushbutton is about 300. How can obtain triggering signal when one of them is pressed without re-edit every single button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an "event filter" that is installed on `QApplication` instance. This filter will receive all the events in your application, afterwards you can check event type and object type to pick the events you are interested in. See my answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33676225/432492) for details.